# Show sibling child categories in left.phtml navigation in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, navigation, category-listing

In the standard left navigation `catalog/navigation/left.phtml` of **Magento 1.9** when entering a child category, with no children of its own, the navigation area is left blank. For **these childless categories only**, I would like to **show sibling categories in the left navigation**.

For example:

Parent Category

- Child A
- Child B
- Child C

In the above scenario, if I navigated to 'Child A' then 'Child A, Child B and Child C' would be shown in the left navigation bar (with Child A ideally being shown in bold).

My current `navigation/left.phtml` code is:

```
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <!--<dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>-->
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Can an edit be suggested to the above, please, to get this working as desired?**

Comment: Your requirement is to show sibling categories if current category don't have child categories. Right? If your current category have child categories then?

Comment: @yorkieMagento , please try my below answer and let me know if any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manged to adapt @Sukumar Gorai answer above to get it working how I wanted it to, as per my original question.

**Revised code for /navigation/left.phtml**.

```
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>
<?php $_countchildren = count($currentCategory->getChildrenCategories()); ?>
<?php if ($_countchildren == 0): { ?>
<?php $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $_categories->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $currentCategory->getParentId()) //siblings have the same parent as the current category
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories
        ->addAttributeToSort('position'); ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <!--<dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>-->
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>"<?php if ($currentCategory->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } elseif ($_countchildren != 0): { ?>
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories() ?>
<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <!--<dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>-->
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>"<?php if ($this->isCategoryActive($_category)): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php } endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

For achieve it you need to edit below file from your theme:

frontend/XYZ/THEME/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     rwd_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2015 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Category layered navigation
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View
 */
?>
<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav<?php if (!$this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?> block-layered-nav--no-filters<?php endif; ?>">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Shop By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content toggle-content">
        <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
            <div class="actions"><a href="<?php echo $this->getClearUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Clear All') ?></a></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($this->canShowOptions()): ?>
            <p class="block-subtitle block-subtitle--filter"><?php echo $this->__('Filter') ?></p>
            <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount()): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php else: 
       $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
       $_categories->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentId()) //siblings have the same parent as the current category
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories
        ->addAttributeToSort('position');//sort by position
    ?>
    <div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <!--<dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>-->
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl();?>"><?php echo $_category->getName();?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. Can you provide code for left.phtml Chirag, as requested, please?

Comment: @YorkieMagento ,  No need to update left.phtml file.

Answer (score 2):

**Code for non-anchor categories:**

Use the below code for **navigation/left.phtml**:

```
<?php if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>
<?php $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $_categories->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $currentCategory->getParentId()) //siblings have the same parent as the current category
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories
        ->addAttributeToSort('position'); ?>

<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <!--<dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>-->
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl() ?>"<?php if ($currentCategory->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You need to set bold for current category then add the following css to your css files:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .current{font-weight: bold;}
</style>
```

**Code for anchor categories:**
Use the below code for **layer/view.phtml**:

```
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category'); ?>
<?php $_categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $_categories->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $currentCategory->getParentId()) //siblings have the same parent as the current category
        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)//get only active categories
        ->addAttributeToSort('position'); ?>

<?php $_count = is_array($_categories)?count($_categories):$_categories->count(); ?>
<?php if($_count): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Browse By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <dl id="narrow-by-list2">
            <!--<dt><?php echo $this->__('Category') ?></dt>-->
            <dd>
                <ol>
                <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_category->getUrl(); ?>"<?php if ($currentCategory->getId() == $_category->getId()): ?> class="current"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_category->getName()) ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </dd>
        </dl>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list2')</script>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($this->canShowBlock()): ?>
<div class="block block-layered-nav">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Shop By') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <?php echo $this->getStateHtml() ?>
        <?php if ($this->getLayer()->getState()->getFilters()): ?>
            <div class="actions"><a href="<?php echo $this->getClearUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Clear All') ?></a></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($this->canShowOptions()): ?>
            <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo $this->__('Shopping Options') ?></p>
            <dl id="narrow-by-list">
                <?php $_filters = $this->getFilters() ?>
                <?php foreach ($_filters as $_filter): ?>
                <?php if($_filter->getItemsCount() && $_filter->getName() != 'Category'): ?>
                    <dt><?php echo $this->__($_filter->getName()) ?></dt>
                    <dd><?php echo $_filter->getHtml() ?></dd>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </dl>
            <script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You need to set bold for current category then add the following css to your css files:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .current{font-weight: bold;}
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry Sukumar, I did choose your answer. However, noticed that this doesn't work as requested, where only childless categories have this new navigation applied. I would like parent categories to behave as they did previously (i.e. their navigation shows children only).